# Marcar JCalendar quando houver evento no dia

Tags: java, calendar

Na minha aplicação Java Desktop, estou pensando em adicionar um JCalendar para informar de forma fácil em que dia existem eventos que serão gravados em um banco de dados.

A minha duvida é saber se é possível fazer um marcação ou mudança de cor no calendário do mês.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você possa usar o setBackground, segue um exemplo:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(calendar.getDate());
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

JPanel jpanel = calendar.getDayChooser().getDayPanel();
Component component[] = jpanel.getComponents();

//arraylist dos eventos
for(int i = 0; i < events.size(); i++)
{
    //mês e ano selecionado em JCalendar
    if(month == events.get(i).getMonth() && year == events.get(i).getYear())
    {
         // Calcular o deslocamento do primeiro dia do mês
         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
         int offset = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;

        //Este valor será diferente de cada mês, devido aos primeiros dias de cada mês
         component[ events.get(i).getDay() + offset ].setBackground(Color.blue); 
    }
}
```